# Xcode 4.2 UITableview Custom cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios5

I have a problem with Custom cell on story board. I need to access labels from the method called

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

How can i define it in my code? When I used IBOutlet Then It may caused the error.

So how could I access the label like

cell.textlable.text ??

[image]

Thanks alot.

Comment: Story Board --> View Controller ---> Add Table View --> Select Cell --> Add Lable and button to cell Then I can populate it.

I need to access those Label and button that I added to custom cell from my code.

are you clear right now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One common solution is to give each label a tag in the storyboard, and then find the label using `viewWithTag:` to find it in your code, like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = blah blah blah ...
    ...
    UILabel *myLabel = [cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *anotherLabel = [cell viewWithTag:2];
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: After I placed the Label on my cell then I can Populate it. I need to call that label from my method. The way you are using here is code the label from your own code. is it ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If you are asking whether I created the UILabel in code, no.  I created it in the XIB and set its tag in the XIB.

Answer (score 13):

I would subclass UITableViewCell. Inside the subclass create the IBOutlets and then you can access them in a regular way and set them up inside interface builder. Just be sure and set your prototype cell to be of that class. then the outlets will show up and you can access them with dot-syntax like you wanted.

An example would be:

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
{
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel* customLabel;

@end
```

and the implementation is just as simple

```
#import CustomCell.h
@implementation CustomCell

@synthesize customLabel;

@end
```

It is that simple,
Then in your method you would do something like this:

```
CustonmCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCell"];
cell.customLabel = //whatever
//or
UILabel* mylabel = cell.customLabel;
```

You can add as many outlets as you would like and access them in a similar manner.

Comment: I like this answer better.  Accessing with the outlets is more obvious than referencing the tag in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

For custom cell in storyboard, use cellWillDisplay method instead of cellForRow to access cell variables.

Step 1. Create a custom MyTableViewCell:UITableViewCell class. Place the IBOutlet variables in this class.

Step 2. On Xcode IB, select the cell, change its class to MyTableViewCell. Then link the IBOutlets.

Step 3. In cellWillDisplayAtIndexPath, access the IBOutlet variables cell.myTextLabel as usual.

EDIT: Correction, if you're using Dynamic prototype, then cellForRowAtIndexPath will work. If you're using static cell then use cellWillDisplayAtIndexPath. If you're using static cell, then the steps above are not applicable, as you will be defining your IBOutlets at UITableView's view controller. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Their is No more method called cellWillDisplay?

Do I have any possibility to do drag and drop the connection to cell or tableview or anything.?

Comment: Pls search Apple doc for the exact cellWillDisplayAtIndexPath method signature.

Comment: you are wrong @rob may off is right. and there is now method called cellwillDisplay?

anyway thanks you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Just an edit to Robs answer. Took me a while as it came up with an error in xcode 4. Changed it to this:
        UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];